# Temporarily Disable a facebook account using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use facebook api to temporarily disable a facebook account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Why would anyone ever give you that permission?

Comment: I'm developing an enterprise app where it makes sense and the user is completely aware of what is happening. So you are saying I just can't do that or that I shouldn't?

Comment: I believe it's not possible. I've used the facebook API for years and never seen or heard of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can ban users who authorize your application so then they no longer able to access application till you do not un-ban him/her.
Here is the function you have to use for this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.banUsers/
To un-ban user you can use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/admin.unbanUsers/

Comment: thanks, but that's not what I meant. I really mean the account, not just for my app.